# Multidimensional Array Filtering PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [license_id] => 172 [valid_from] => 2014-10-13 14:39:32 [valid_till] => 2020-10-22 00:00:00 [us_user_user_id] => 810 [us_group_group_id] => [li_voucher_voucher_id] => 90128 [pr_product_product_ids] => 91,92,93 [li_license_setting_license_setting_id] => 55 [li_voucher_setting_voucher_setting_id] => 222 [product_data] => {"answer_layer":true} ) [1] => Array ( [license_id] => 173 [valid_from] => 2014-10-13 14:39:48 [valid_till] => 2020-10-21 14:39:48 [us_user_user_id] => 810 [us_group_group_id] => [li_voucher_voucher_id] => 90129 [pr_product_product_ids] => 94 [li_license_setting_license_setting_id] => 73 [li_voucher_setting_voucher_setting_id] => 223 [product_data] => {"answer_layer":true} ) [2] => Array ( [license_id] => 371 [valid_from] => 2015-01-07 12:05:36 [valid_till] => 2021-01-15 12:05:36 [us_user_user_id] => 810 [us_group_group_id] => [li_voucher_voucher_id] => 89008 [pr_product_product_ids] => 173 [li_license_setting_license_setting_id] => 56 [li_voucher_setting_voucher_setting_id] => 160 [product_data] => {"answer_layer":true} ) [3] => Array ( [license_id] => 441 [valid_from] => 2015-03-04 16:10:18 [valid_till] => 2016-03-03 16:10:18 [us_user_user_id] => 810 [us_group_group_id] => [li_voucher_voucher_id] => 124457 [pr_product_product_ids] => 243 [li_license_setting_license_setting_id] => 201 [li_voucher_setting_voucher_setting_id] => 315 [product_data] => ) )
```

I want to filter the the value [valid_till] where the value from [license_id] = 441.

I already filtered the specific license with license_id 441 with the next code:

```
$filtered = array_filter($userlicenses, function($v) { return $v['license_id'] == '441'; });
```

But this gives me the complete array. I want only the [valid_till] where [license_id] = 441.

Comment: `$filtered = array_filter($userlicenses, function($v) { return $v['license_id'] == '441' ? $v['valid_till'] : false; });`? using array_filter, inside the function, you should be able to return the part you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_reduce` is an easy way to just return the value:

```
$result = array_reduce($userlicenses,

                       function($c, $v) {
                            return $v['license_id'] == '441' ? $v['valid_till'] : false;
                       }
);
```

And an `array_column` method:

```
$result = array_column($userlicenses, 'valid_from', 'license_id')[441];
```

Comment: I used the array_reduce method. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

"Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from array is returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved." [function.array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

This means your variable `$filtered` is an array again/still.
If it's only one dimensional (i.e. you have always exactly one result) you can simply access the key `valid_till` of the first element returned this way:

```
<?php

$userlicenses = array( 
    0 => array ( 
        'license_id' => 172,
        'valid_from' => '2014-10-13 14:39:32',
        'valid_till' => '2020-10-22 00:00:00'
    ),
    1 => array ( 
        'license_id' => 173,
        'valid_from' => '2014-10-13 14:39:48',
        'valid_till' => '2020-10-21 14:39:48'
    ),
    2 => array ( 
        'license_id' => 371,
        'valid_from' => '2015-01-07 12:05:36',
        'valid_till' => '2021-01-15 12:05:36'
    ),
    3 => array ( 
        'license_id' => 441,
        'valid_from' => '2015-03-04 16:10:18',
        'valid_till' => '2016-03-03 16:10:18'
    )
);

$filtered = array_filter($userlicenses, function($v) { return $v['license_id'] == '441'; });
var_dump( $filtered );
if( is_array( $filtered ) )
{
   $first_el = reset( $filtered );
   $valid_till = $first_el['valid_till'];
   var_dump( $valid_till );
}

?>
```